# Format display in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with the following information:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft© Windows Server© 2008 Standard 
OS Version:                6.0.6002 Service Pack 2 Build 6002
System Manufacturer:       IBM
System Model:              IBM 3850 M2 / x3950 M2 -[7233Z1H]-
```

I need to use powrshell to read and format the display.. My existing code is this:

```
$Array = @()
Get-Content <txtfilename> | foreach {
$Test = $_
$Title = $Test.split(":")[0]
$Content = $Test.split(":")[1]
$Obj = New-Object System.Object
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -value $Title -Name Title
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -value $Content -Name Value
$Array += $Obj
}

$Array | Select Title,Value | Export-Csv <csvfilename> -NoTypeInformation
```

It displays the information as follows listed:

```
Title      Content
OS Name                         Microsoft? Windows Server? 2008 Standard 
OS Version                      6.0.6002 Service Pack 2 Build 6002
System Manufacturer             IBM
System Model                    IBM 3850 M2 / x3950 M2 -[7233Z1H]-
```

I need the information displayed in a single line like this:

```
ServerName, OS Name , OS Version,  System Manufacture, Sytem model,
TestServer1, Microsoft Windows, 6.0.6002 Service Pack 2, IBM, IBM 3850
```

Thanks

Comment: Would simplest approach be "Get-Content txtfilename.csv" - assuming the original input really is CSV as you say it is?  The output you want is essentially the CSV file format.  BTW, your desired output shows a ServerName field yet no where in the post do you show where that comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a second answer for the more advanced case, where you don't know how many unique headers you have or what they're called.  As long as they're consistently the same and in the same order, the following will work:

```
$filePath = "C:\users\chris\desktop\info.txt"
$headers = @()
[int]$headerCount = 0
$endUnique = $false
Get-Content $filePath | % {
    $header = ($_.split(':')[0] -replace '\s+', ' ').Trim()
    if (($headers -notcontains $header) -and (!$endUnique)){
        $headers += $header
        $headerCount += 1
    }
    else{
        $endUnique = $true
    }
}
$headerRow = ""
$headers | % {$headerRow += $_ + ","}
$headerRow = $headerRow.Substring(0,$headerRow.Length-1)

[int]$i = 1
$outString = ""
Get-Content $filePath | % {
    $lineContent = ($_.split(':')[1] -replace '\s+', ' ').Trim()
    if ($i -lt $headerCount){
        $outstring += $linecontent + ','
        $i += 1
    }
    else{
        $outstring += $linecontent + "`r`n"
        $i = 1
    }
}
$outstring = $headerRow+ "`r`n"+$outstring
```

I'd like to see the other answers from more advanced PowerShell users.

Answer (score 0):

First, just a quick correction.  You say you have a CSV.  It looks like you have a formatted text file and you want to make a CSV out of it.

Following that assumption, something like this should get you started.  It assumes that the text document has either only those 4 items in it, or those 4 items are repeated multiple times - always in the same order, and without a space in between them.  Reformatting text files is never fun without a bunch of examples of how they could look.

That being said, the following should get you started.

```
[int]$i = 1
$outString = ""
Get-Content C:\users\chris\desktop\info.txt | % {
    #Take the line, remove the title, remove whitespaces from inside of the line and trim whitespaces from the outside.
    $lineContent = ($_.split(':')[1] -replace '\s+', ' ').Trim()
    #Chunk them together...
    if ($i -lt 4){
        $outstring += $linecontent + ','
        $i += 1
    }
    #or insert a return, new line
    else{
        $outstring += $linecontent + "`r`n"
        $i = 1
    }
}
#Add a header row.  Now $outstring is your CSV formatted text.
$outstring = "OSName,OSVersion,SystemMfg,SystemModel`r`n"+$outstring
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the update. That works fine. The other thing is I want to dynamically add the header as at time I don't know the names of the header row. I.e. using an array for the header.. thx

Comment: Are there ever going to me multiple computers described in one text file? If so, will the headers be the same for each object?

Comment: Hi Chris, also the reason why I used add-member is there will be different files with diffent amount of content but same format and I don't know ahead of time what the content headers or contents will be. So I have to use array all through out and not limit to i.e. $ -lt 4

Comment: Will there be a blank line between each computer or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
$object = New-Object System.Object
Get-Content TestServer1-OSInfo.txt | % {
 If($_.Contains(":")){
    $Left = $_.split(":")[0].TrimStart().TrimEnd()
     $Right = $_.split(":")[1].TrimStart().TrimEnd()
      $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name $Left -value $Right
    }
}
$object | Export-Csv TestServer1-OSInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```